# Which volume has Mikasa's backstory?

Tags: attack-on-titan

My favorite episode is the one with Mikasa's backstory. The manga has so much more detail so I wanted her backstory in the manga.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are referring to the **6th Episode** of *Attack on Titan*. This episode adapts both Chapter 5 and 6 of the manga and includes Mikasa's backstory. I'd also recommend reading the second volume of *Attack on Titan: Lost Girls*, which is also about Mikasa.